# Group elements after being put in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that is already structured a certain way. It looks like this roughly, but with many more rows. These rows are generated based on how much information is pulled from a database.

[image]

The code looks somewhat like this,

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class='master'>
        <div class='dates'>
            <!-- Left side of first internal div -->
            <div class='ResourceHeader'>
                <p>Resource</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Right side of first internal div -->
            <div class='DatesHeader'>
                <div class='dates'>
                    <p>Date1</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Insert more dates -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='secondRow'>
            <!-- Left side of second row -->
            <div class='Resource1'>
                <p>P1</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Right side of second row -->
            <div class='date1'>
                <p>D1</p>
                <!-- Insert more dates -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='thirdRow'>
            <!-- Left side of third row -->
            <div class='Resource2'>
                <p>P2</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Right side of third row -->
            <div class='date1'>
                <p>D1</p>
                <!-- Insert more dates -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the website to be structured like this,

[image]

I just want to surround the elements in different `divs` because the `div` on the right will scroll to the right if more content(dates) are added while the `div` on the left stays still.

Is there a way to achieve this using anything? Or would I have to go back and change how my website is being rendered after the info is being pulled from the database.

Or can I just assign the `divs` with the `Date1, Date2, ...` and `D1, D2, ...` with a class and just have those `divs` with the certain class move?

Comment: it looks like a table. why don't you use table for it?

Comment: No magic involved. You need to create outer columns and loop your data in both outer columns to generate the tabular output for each

Comment: If you have access to your data before rendering it, just modify how it is rendered. If not, you will can always rely on javaScript to move elements around in DOM after they are rendered.

Comment: I don't really want to touch how it's being rendered, unless necessary. Isn't moving the elements around in the DOM time consuming? What would be ideal, is if I can just assign the `divs` that I want to move different classes and just move those `divs`. Meaning add a scroll bar for those `divs`.